# How to get last week's data from the previous day in postgressql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to extract data for a week from previous day.
For example:
Today's date : `21-06-2021`
I want a week's data from : `13-06-2021 to 20-06-2021`
**In Postgressql**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
select * from ur_tbl
where 
  date_clmn >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 day') and
  date_clmm < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: That second comparison should be `<`.